# use network folder files for project in PhpStorm8

Tags: phpstorm

How can I use the files on the network folder for my project in PhpStorm v8?
My xampp server is on local ip address - 192.168.1.12.
We need to maintain a common folder on network drive for coding purposes.

Comment: It's not recommended to work with files over network directly: you may experience slow downs and temp freezes out of nowhere if your network is slow (HDD will be faster). You better have local copy and set up automatic deployment to your network folder. Or even better: use proper VCS.

Comment: Yeah. That's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. Mapped a network drive and then, used the same drive to access the code.